# Excel Queries - VBA Refresh and Wait

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with about 10 queries in it.  I am refreshing multiple queries through VBA no problem.

One query (really more of a transform) - takes the data from one of the above queries [Let's say Query A] and transforms/calculates.  Which means I need to do the following:

1. Run Query A
2. Wait for Query A to Complete
3. Run Transform Query

I can't seem to get them to time properly... is there a way to create an event to trigger the completion of Query A?

Answer (score 0):

I changed all of my queries to NOT run in the background.  That made them all synchronous. problem solved.